# Remote debugging with GDB on STM32H7 without PC connected to evaluation board

Tags: debugging, gdb, stm32, gdbserver

I'm working on STM32H7 evaluation boards (Nucleo-144 and EVAL2). My IDE is STM32CUbeIDE.

My goal is to debug remotely: run STM32CubeIDE (or another IDE) on a Linux server and connect to the board through the network.

I could run successfully the following setup:

- connect the board to a local PC
- launch GDBserver on this local PC
- on the distant Linux server, setup the Debug Configuration to connect to the remote GDB server.

This is working fine. But I need to go further: I'd like to remove the local PC, ie. the board would be connected directly through ethernet to the network.

I've been told that there is a JTAG/Ethernet adapter for Xilinx, called Smartlynq that allows to do that, but the way it works is a bit confusing for me.

Do you know about an equivalent for STM32 ecosystem ?

Would there be another setup to debug remotely without a PC in between ?

Answer (score 2):

The [Segger J-Link PRO](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/j-link-pro/) is a JTAG/SWD debugger for ARM that supports Ethernet. Like the other J-Link models, it should work fine for STM32.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I don't really understand how it works though. Does it execute a gdb server ?

Comment: You run the `JLinkGDBServer` on a PC and specify the IP address of the J-Link adapter to connect to. Very similar to USB, just that it connects via network to the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

## Use a Raspberry PI as a debug adapter.

It would be *somewhat* cheaper than a JLINK Pro. If there is WLAN available, take a Pi Zero W, otherwise you'd need one of the bigger ones with Ethernet. Set it up for remote work (enable ssh, set a fixed IP address etc), then you can disable the GUI desktop, and disconnect the display and the keyboard.

**Running `gdbserver`**

The Pi has an ARM CPU which supports the Thumb instruction set but not Thumb-2, so its native `gdbserver` *might* be able to debug a Cortex-M7 controller. If it can't, then you have to install the `gdb-arm-none-eabi` package on the Pi.

**Connectint to the target board**

There are two alternatives.

- Connect the onboard debug adapter to an USB port on the PI, and run `openocd` just the way you do it on a PC.
- Bypass the onboard debug adapter, and connect some pins on the Pi directly to the `SWD` pins of the target. You have to remove some jumpers to disable the onboard debug adapters. There is [a tutorial at Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/programming-microcontrollers-using-openocd-on-raspberry-pi/overview) on how to compile and use `openocd` with native `SWD` support.

Comment: Thank you for the proposal @berendi. It sounds smart for small budgets, even if it looks a bit complicated to set up.